# WiFi not working on 16.04/Intel 8260

Tags: 16.04, wireless, intel

I have a Gigabyte laptop with Intel 8260 chipset. My 16.04 installation has no Wi-fi enabled. I read many blogs and followed the steps, but it did not help in anyways.  I am badly stuck with this. I really appreciate any r solution on this

I have tried the options like downloading the .tgz file, installing after editing for 24F3 etc. None of them work  for me.

When I run: 
`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

I get this message:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:1010]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
05:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1b21:1242]
```

And for: `rfkill list all`

I get this message:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and

sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl

returns

```
[    7.548947] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.625939] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625949] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625955] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625961] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625966] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-29.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625972] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-28.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625977] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625982] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625987] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625993] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.625998] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.626003] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.626004] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    7.626007] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-8000C-22
[    7.626008] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-8000C-33
[    7.626009] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ahh! It looks like the driver *iwlwifi* loaded. Let's see what the message log says. 'sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Edit your question to add the result.

Comment: I edited the question with output. thanks for all the help

Comment: Follow the process in the duplicate, reboot and you should be all set!